# $P(X+Y=n) = \infty $ Why?

Tags: probability

$X,Y \sim Geom(p)$, $0<p<1$ where $X,Y$ are indipendent.

I'm failing to calculate the probability of $X+Y=n$ where $n>0$ integer.

$$P(X+Y=n)= \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} P(X+Y=n | Y=y)*P(Y=y) $$
$$= \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} P(X=n-y | Y=y)*P(Y=y) $$
$$= \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} P(X=n-y)*P(Y=y) $$
$$= \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{n-y-1}p(1-p)^{y-1}p $$
$$= \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{n-2}p^{2} $$
$$= (1-p)^{n-2}p^{2}\sum_{y=1}^{\infty} 1=\infty $$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The sum should be from $1$ to $n$ or something like that.

Comment: The mistake is in going from $P(X=n-y)$ to the formula that follows. $P(X=-1)=0$, for example.

Comment: Yes, y goes from 0 to n

Comment: Thanks. It's $1$ to $n-1$ because if not, X will be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(X=n-y)$ is not $p(1-p)^{n-y-1}$. Just like $P(X=k)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }k<1\\ p(1-p)^{k-1}&\text{if }k\ge 1\end{cases}$, we have that $P(X=n-y)$ is $0$ if $n-y<1$ and it is $p(1-p)^{n-y-1}$ if $n-y\ge1$.